# Unable to display upload images from s3 bucket in asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, base64

I try to display images from s3 bucket in asp.net mvc I get the base64 encoded response. but is not display image in the view

first image  is in binary encoding, rather than Base64.
so I convert into base64 with this
 function _arrayBufferToBase64()

This is my view

```
   <img data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,{{str}}" 
   alt="MyImage">
```

This is my MVC controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetReadObject()
    {
        string responseBody = "";
        try
        {
            using (IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    Key = keyName
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = s3client.GetObject(request))
                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
                    Console.WriteLine("The object's title is {0}", title);

                    responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return Json(responseBody, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/User/Dashboard/GetReadObject',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
   }).then(function (response) {
    alert("1");
    console.log(response);
    var str = _arrayBufferToBase64(response.data);
    $scope.getImage = str;
    alert(str);
    console.log(str);
    // str is base64 encoded.
},
   function (response) {
    console.error('error in getting static img.');
});


function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
}
})
```

Comment: Why don't you just return the public URL from S3?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,{{getImage}}" 
   alt="MyImage">
```

As you mentioned in your controller, str is simple javascript variable that you could not use with View. As you assign str value to $scope.getImage **($scope.getImage = str)** You can use {{getImage}} with angular expression in your View.